# getting error : Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'polls/<int:question_id>/'] in django

Tags: python, django

I am newbie here in django, when i run my app, I am getting this error

```
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'polls/<int:question_id>/']
```

here i have uploaded my code for index.html and urls.py can you please check my code and help me to resolve this issue ?

index.html

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for question in latest_question_list %}
            {% if question.id %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
            {% else %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    url('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    url('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    url('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    url('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),

]
```

Comment: `<int:question_id>` is a syntax for `path` not `url` function.

Comment: adding to @IvanStarostin, `url` function takes the arguments as named regex grouped `?P<question_id>`

Comment: if i import the path from django.conf.urls import path , then getting error ImportError: cannot import name path

Comment: because it's not from django.conf.urls , Google to see where it comes from

Comment: it is not working for this as well from django.urls import path

Comment: Please tell your Django version.

Comment: i have resolved it thanks